# How to save logs of Node.js running in CyberPanel?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, logging, cyber-panel, openlitespeed

I am currently running a Cyber Panel v2.1 + Ubuntu + Node v14.4 on an EC2 T2.Small Instance. Using the context menu in the Open Lite Speed Interface, I run a Node.JS Website. However, their are issues with its functionality, particularly when I try to require the Mongoose or MongoDB Package.

As of now, I don't have a way to see the error logs or console logs that are generating, only the access logs. Is their a way I can configure something on either CyberPanel or Node.Js that I can get the console logs & the access logs of the project so that I can fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enable console log by setting environment variable

```
LSNODE_CONSOLE_LOG=</path/to/your/console/log/file>
```

when you configure the application.

Comment: LSNODE_CONSOLE_LOG=</VH_ROOT/logs/site.com.error_log> - I added this to the context menu, > environment variables but the logs don't seem to appear, I have rebooted the server as well

Comment: Make sure `/VH_ROOT/logs/` directory exists, and the user that application running as has write permission to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you have root access then you should be able to see the node servers and your application level logs under `/usr/local/lsws/logs/`.